# XCode 8 Provisioning Profiles for Sticker extensions

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am adding a sticker extension to an existing ios app.

The app bundle is in the form:

```
com.app_name.company_name
```

The sticker bundle is in the form:

```
com.app_name.company_name.sticker
```

Do I need to generate a separate provisioning profile, or can I leverage my existing profile?

Thanks!

Comment: you can create one wild card provisioning that is enough

Answer (score 1):

If you use any of the enabled services (e.g., push notifications), you can't use wildcard provisioning.  In this case you must create a separate provisioning profile for the app and app.sticker.